# Update database with php triggered by ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap button, this:

```
<button type="button" id="turnOff" class="btn">Turn Off</button>
```

that calls an ajax function into "bootstrap.min.js".

This is the ajax function:

```
$('#turnOff').click(function () {
    $.ajax({ method: "POST",
            url: "/sys/class/buttonHandler.php", 
            data: {mode: 0 , id: 2 }
           });
});
```

This function should "insert" the 'mode' and the 'id' into the file "buttonHandler.php" which contains the following:

```
<?php
include ('sys/class/class.global.php');
$mode = $_POST['mode'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
set($mode, $id);
?>
```

the function "set()" is into another php, "class.global.php" that's the only php with proved and worked database access, and it's the following:

```
function set($mode, $id)
{
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET test = '$mode' WHERE id = '$id'");
}
```

Unfortunately all this doesn't update anything and I'm not able to understand why.

If someone can help me that's would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check for errors for PHP/MySQL and look at your console. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: The query works fine but I'm not able to see errors with the code because I'm working directly with the live version..

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump()`'s and error reporting should narrow the problem down, but from what I can see so far the problem is your include.

Your script is at `/sys/class/buttonHandler.php`, relative to the web-root.

In that script you do:

```
include ('sys/class/class.global.php');
```

So that path evaluates on the server to:

```
WEBROOT . '/sys/class/sys/class/class.global.php'
```

And that is probably not what you have in mind.

Using `require` you will probably get that same message.

So you most likely just need:

```
require 'class.global.php';    // or include of course
```

Comment: I use that same include in other files and everywhere works fine. I think it's a problem of the Ajax that doesn't set mode and id into buttonHandler.php

Comment: Also, I'm using microsoft WebMatrix and I'm working directly with the live version so I don't have a console and I don't know what to use to debug the code, if you have any suggestions would be very appreciated. Thanks